# Magento 2 Change image size of product detail page

Tags: magento2, product-images, image-resize

Need to change product image size 850 X 750 on the product detail page
I made changes in file view.xml but width is taking randomly
/app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/etc/view.xml
product_page_image_medium width 900 and height 750

Comment: Do you use any theme?

Comment: @RiteshSantra thanks for the reply Yes I am using Magento 2 Couture Fashion Theme

Comment: check this link --- https://nwdthemes.com/2017/12/19/magento-2-product-image-size/